# Changing Multiple Filenames in multiple Folders with Batch

Tags: powershell, filenames

I have several Folder which contain from 5 to 20 Files with all different names. They get replaced every week, so the Name of each File also changes. But i Need them to have specific Names so i can upload them by using my SQL loader.

Is there a way to create a Batch file, which goes into every Folder that i specify, select all Files and changes all the names? Perfect Solution would just be a upcounting number like: file1.xml, file2.xml etc.

Since im a total newbie to Batch i searched around a bit and found following code, but it only changes the files in 1 specific Folder.

```
Dir *.xml | ForEach-Object  -begin { $count=1 }  
-process { rename-item $_ -NewName "$count.xml"; $count++ }
```

**Update 1**
I found the working code which allows me to rename the files in a Folder as i want them to be. I would just Need a code, that allows me to do this to several other Folders at the same time or automatically one after another.

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set a=1
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b *.xml') do (
ren "%%i" "!a!.xml" 
set /a a+=1
)
```

Comment: Through which language/database you want to achieve this?

Comment: I think powershell would be the easiest to achieve a solution the closest to this.

Comment: Not i think, tell us the exact tool and other tool options as well that you need to use.

Comment: PowerShell is *not* batch! If you want to use PowerShell, edit your question.

Comment: @SomethingDark i know that but you can use powershell in a Batch file so it can initiate the command using "powershell -Command"

Comment: It's still a totally separate language that you need to include in your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion 

set a=1

rem make old name to prevent same name collision
for /D %%i in (*) do (
    cd %%i
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir /b *.xml') do (
        ren "%%j" "%%j-old.xml" 
    ) 
    cd ..
)

rem rename process
for /D %%i in (*) do (
    cd %%i
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('dir /b *.xml') do (
        ren "%%j" "!a!.xml" 
        set /a a+=1
    ) 
    cd ..
)

echo Done
pause
Start .
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PowerShell code to do the same for several folders (sub-folders)

```
$path = 'Z:\'

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter *.xml -Recurse | ForEach-Object -Begin {
  [int]$count = '1'
} -Process {
  Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$count.xml" -ErrorAction Stop 
  $count++
}
```